# Function call / Referencing from within a string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=DOGE&tsyms=INR")
```

I have the above given function, and I have to call this function again with different parameters i.e. "DOGE" and "INR" will have to be replaced with a new set of parameters.

But I am not able to figure out how to reference cell within the url here.

[Column_Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdxHY.png) The column which has to be iterated over looks like this.

I tried using cell reference directly, string manipulation but it didn't work as it didn't recognise it as a formula.

```
IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=A2&tsyms=INR")
IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LEFT(A2,10)&tsyms=INR")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this formula and drag down

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym="&B2&"&tsyms=INR")
```

[image]